# Vertical text sliding, one phrase after another

Tags: css, css-animations

I am struggling to come up with an text silder using CSS animation. What I am after is to display one phrase at a time from a list of phrases. A phrase slides in from the right, holds (pauses) and slide out from the right after which the next phrase slides in. And so on.

This is what I've got working so far. But it seems using the animate delay methode is not the way to go. Some one any suggestions on how to get these text phrases sliding in one after another neatly?

```css
    ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .wrapper div {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .list li {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 600px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .item-a {
        animation: slideIn 4s forwards cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.67, 0.29, 0.98) infinite;
    }
    .item-b {
        /* Start with 4 seconds delay */
        animation: slideIn 4s 4s forwards cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.67, 0.29, 0.98) infinite;
    }
    .item-c {
        /* Start with 8 seconds delay */
        animation: slideIn 4s 8s forwards cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.67, 0.29, 0.98) infinite;
    }

    @keyframes slideIn {
        0% {
            transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        20% {
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            opacity: 1;
        }
        80% {
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            opacity: 1;
        }
        99.99% {
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <ul class="list slider">
        <li class="item-a">
            You are cool!
        </li>
        <li class="item-b">
            Well done!
        </li>
        <li class="item-c">
            Keep on going!
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your animation seems to be working, except for the `infinite` which causes the previous items to reappear on top of the previous animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with pure CSS/HTML and with using animation-delay - but the %s in the animation and the overall length of the animation need to change.

Each phrase is to show for 4seconds and then disappear for 8 seconds while the other phrases show, so the overall animation time will be 12seconds and the first third of that the phrase will show and for the two thirds remaining it will be hidden.

Dividing the %s in your animation by 3 we get to:

```
   @keyframes slideIn {
        0% {
            transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        6.66% {
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            opacity: 1;
        }
        26.66% {
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            opacity: 1;
        }
        33.30% {
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        33.33% {
            transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
```

Now, using the animation delays you have already built in but changing the overall animation-duration for each phrase to 12s, the phrases will come one after the other forever.

Here's the snippet:

```css
    ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .wrapper div {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .list li {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 600px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .item-a {
        animation: slideIn 12s forwards cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.67, 0.29, 0.98) infinite;
    }
    .item-b {
        /* Start with 4 seconds delay */
        animation: slideIn 12s 4s forwards cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.67, 0.29, 0.98) infinite;
    }
    .item-c {
        /* Start with 8 seconds delay */
        animation: slideIn 12s 8s forwards cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.67, 0.29, 0.98) infinite;
    }

    @keyframes slideIn {
        0% {
            transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        6.66% {
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            opacity: 1;
        }
        26.66% {
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            opacity: 1;
        }
        33.30% {
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        33.33% {
            transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <ul class="list slider">
        <li class="item-a">
            You are cool!
        </li>
        <li class="item-b">
            Well done!
        </li>
        <li class="item-c">
            Keep on going!
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

For a different number of phrases you would alter the %s accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using javascript (not a direct answer to your question perhaps), you can solve it by removing the `li` element once the animation has finished, and then adding a new one with a different text.

The big advantage is that you can easily add more texts to the list without having to adjust the CSS file.

```js
const texts = ["You are cool", "Well done", "Keep on going!"]
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
let counter = 0


function addAnimation() {
const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = texts[counter];
    ul.appendChild(li);


  li.classList.add("animated-item");
  li.addEventListener('animationend', (e) => {
    e.target.remove();
    counter++;
    if(counter == texts.length) counter = 0;
    addAnimation();
  });
}

addAnimation();
```

```css
 ul {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

.wrapper div {
  width: 100%;
}

.list li {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0.4;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.animated-item {
  animation: slideIn 4s forwards cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.67, 0.29, 0.98);
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <ul class="list slider">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```